# Rigging - Unwanted "Stepped on chewing gum" effect?

Tags: mesh, rigging, vertices, weight-painting

I'm still learning, so please be patient. And I'm sure this has been answered on this site before, but I'm not sure what to search for. I have imported a Genesis 9 Daz character into Blender using Diffeomorphic, and finally got it working the way I wanted after several hours or trial and error - or so I thought! Some parts of the mesh seems to be sticking when I move the armature around. Just small parts, so I don't know how to fix/troubleshoot this. The image shows an example. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: You need to assign these vertices to the vertex group they should be part of, but maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Thanks! I think I must have messed up the vertex groups trying to make masks for the clothes. Re-importing the character and re-doing the masks manually did the trick.